# Fast way to count neighbouring points in 3D array

Tags: optimization, fortran

I have a code where I want to loop over all points in a grid, and for each point check if a given condition holds for a sufficient number of neighbouring points. Additionally, I have periodic boundaries on the grid.

The problem is very similar to the Game of Life.

My current code looks something like this

```
do k=1,ksize; do j=1,jsize; do i=1,isize ! Loop over all points
  ncount = 0
  kkloop: do kk=k-1,k+1 ! Loop over neighbours
    ktmp = kk
    if(kk>ksize) ktmp = 1 ! Handle periodic boundary
    if(kk<1) ktmp = ksize
    do jj=j-1,j+1
      jtmp = jj
      if(jj>jsize) jtmp = 1
      if(jj<1) jtmp = jsize
      do ii=i-1,i+1
        if(ii == 0 .and. jj == 0 .and. kk == 0) cycle ! Skip self
        itmp = ii
        if(ii>isize) itmp = 1
        if(ii<1) itmp = isize

        if(grid(itmp,jtmp,ktmp)) ncount = ncount + 1 ! Check condition for neighbour
        if(ncount > threshold) then ! Enough neigbours with condition?
          do_stuff(i,j,k)
          break kkloop
        end if
      end do
    end do
  end do
end do; end do; end do
```

This is neither elegant, nor probably very efficient. Is there a better way to do this? This code will be repeated a lot, so I would like to make it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll work this out in 2D, leave it to you to inflate to 3D.

The first thing I'd do is pad the array with a halo of depth equal to the depth of the neighbourhood you are interested in.  So, if your array is declared as, say

```
real, dimension(100,100) :: my_array
```

and you are interested in the 8 immediate neighbours of each cell,

```
real, dimension(0:101,0:101) :: halo_array
.
.
.
halo_array(1:100,1:100) = my_array
halo_array(0,:) = my_array(100,:)
! repeat for each border, mutatis mutandis
```

This will save a lot of time checking for the boundary and will be worth doing whether or not you follow the next suggestion. You could do this 'in place' if you like, I mean just expand `my_array` rather than copy it.

For an elegant solution you could write something like this

```
forall (i=1:100,j=1:100)
   if (logical_function_of(my_array(i-1,j),my_array(i+1,j),my_array(i,j-1),my_array(i,j+1),...) then
      do_stuff(my_array(i,j))
   end if
end forall
```

Here, `logical_function_of()` returns true when the neighbourhood of `my_array(i,j)` satisfies your criteria.  I got tired after listing the N,S,E,W neighbours and for production code I'd probably write this as a function of the indices anyway. In my experience `forall` is elegant (to some) but not as high-performing as nested loops.

Comment: +1 for clear code and for _mutatis_ _mutandis_, which I've never seen used in a computing context before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kd-tree or an octree to subdivide the 3d array. A space filling curve like a z morton order curve is useful in 3d to create a key for the eight cubes. But this works best with power of 2 3d arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `grid` function 27 times for every point on the grid. If it is an expensive call you would like to call it less times.

For instance, if the probability of `grid` returning a true value is low, you can call it for every point on the grid and store those for which the condition holds in a kd-tree. Then it is easier to iterate over the points inside the kd-tree counting the neighbours for every point.

Otherwise, you could use a bit matrix of dimension `isize*jsize*3` to cache the values of grid for all the points with `kk=k-1,k+1`. If that is too big, you can go for an intermediate solution using a bit matrix of size `isize*3*3` for caching.

Comment: Every time I read the code `grid(itmp,jtmp,ktmp)` looks like an array access statement to me, not a function call.

Comment: Especially when you loop over `ktmp` in the outermost loop and over `itmp` in the innermost one, it looks like an array access statement.

Comment: Well, we are all just guessing. The reading of the question (*for each point check if a given condition*) made me think `grid` was a function. Let's see if the OP clarifies it.